# User receives "Oops something bad happened" when trying to post a question to meta

Tags: support, bug

[A user tried to post a Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168263/question-ban-meter-feature-request/168266#comment495928_168266) only to receive the "Oops, something bad happened" message.  Since he can't post a meta question complaining about the bug, I'm doing it for him.

Here's his text:

> Okey, but...I'm always getting this "Ooops something bad happened"-message. I'm clicking on the "Ask Question" button, then I need to login (again, altough I'm already logged in), and after the login it starts again with the start page. I did everything, deleted cookies and cache, but it just won't work. So I'm not able to post any questions on meta. And, well, it works with another profile I opened up just for this reason. So it clearly a ban on my profile...

I'll update this question as he gives us information, but my question:

Can you check the logs and see if people are getting errors when posting questions?

Comment: Did he disable all extensions/add-ons/plugins in his browser? I've seen more than one case of such things breaking functionality in the sites.

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki ;-).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Looking at his profile, he managed to ask a question on SO an hour ago, so seems unlikely (assuming he's using the same browser/client etc etc)

Comment: @Jon: The problem was only on meta...and existed for several days. However, since I did a login with a Firefox browser, it works now. Probably a crashed user session? Who knows.

Comment: I saw on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need that Opera 10.x isn't supported. So a good question may be: What about a banner to the users if they are using an non-supported browser? Because the GUI works very well...but the login on stackexchange has huge problems with unsupported browser.

Comment: @marcus if you could edit this question (or comment on *this* question) with the browser specifics, it would help. Otherwise this question is a bit useless.

Comment: Allright: I'm using Opera 10.10, so no HTML 5 (due to several reasons). Once I did a login with an old Opera browser 9.xx, and this site didn't work well afterwards: I was experiencing problems posting questions with my profile. After a few days, I was able to post questions again on stackoverflow (I don't know why it worked again!), but it still didn't work on meta.stackoverflow with Opera 10.10. And it worked with another profile I opened up just for this reason, so it was no browser problem. However, since several days - rather weeks - I couldn't post anything on meta.

Comment: It didn't really bother me until I wanted to post a question on meta. However again, I did a login with Firefox 16, and afterwards it worked again: I was able to post questions with Opera 10.10 on meta. So somehow my profile on the server was...screwed. And I needed a newer browser to reset it.

Comment: I'm not a fan of banner showing your browser is not supported. I have FireFor 3.5, which is almost surely "unsupported", yet I can use the site without any problems ;)

Comment: Why? There must be only a small check box: "Please never show me this banner" and everything is allright for you. Oh, well, it also needs a row in the user DB of stackexchange. ;)

Comment: @Marcus - you are logging out before hitting ask every time, so an authentication token is not matching...are you logged in from multiple browsers and one may be trying to logout?  I see your IP bouncing all around the place in a short time window here.