# How to identify cause of Post Ban

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I am being banned suddenly from posting answers. I want to identify the posts which contribute towards this ban. I learned from the Help Center that only way to lift a Post Ban is to improve the answers or comments. 
But for me to improve I need to know where have I gone wrong. Please guide me towards a section in SO where I could locate which answers / comments have made the algorithm ban me from posting.

Comment: have a look at [help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: We don't know; the exact algorithm is not disclosed. Generally speaking, improving deleted posts with downvotes would be a good starting point.

Comment: Looks for anything with downvotes. Including messages you have deleted.

Comment: As far as I can see, you do not have any post bans on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Siva, are you sure you're experiencing an answer ban and not a content problem with the answer you want to post?

Comment: You do have an answer ban on Programmers, however. At least 2 of your "answers" (now deleted) should have been comments. I realize you do not have enough reputation to comment there, but if you had actually composed a full answer, that would have done it. Of the remaining answers, one has gotten a number of downvotes. All of these are contributing to the answer ban.

Comment: Now, that last answer looks much better thanks to your edits and the fact that you expanded on that answer to make it OK. If it gets a few upvotes, that may very well lift you out of the answer ban. However, you are likely on the edge of it and one bad answer could drop you back into it.

Comment: I really did not understand why did this question got Vote Down. Is it wrong to improve answers by learning and correcting it. No doubt @user64738 is right. It is neither progressive and nor corrective.

Comment: @Oded, even after editing it the ban did not lift. I am really surprised to get a Vote Down on this question. The very point I am discussing this here isn't it an indication enough for improving the content. All I ask here is where do I find out what has gone wrong and how do I fix it. Help Centre talks about how but not where. There is no status indicator of how close or how far am I from the getting banned or getting the ban lifted.

Comment: @SivaSenthil http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168263/question-ban-meter-feature-request?rq=1

Comment: @Michael thanks for posting this. Indeed it is required for all who want to contribute and grow.

Comment: @SivaSenthil Just to be clear, I don't support such a meter, for the reasons outlined in that discussion.

Comment: @SivaSenthil: there is a *long* history of people posting about their question or answer ban, without having read the help information provided. Quite often such posts go hand in hand with demands or 'heart-wrenching' pleas for the ban to be lifted, without much indication that the user actually learned anything about why they might be banned. Your post was almost certainly viewed in that light.

Comment: From Meta.P.SE on a question ban: "... (I'd have to check the code to see exactly what triggered this, but so far as I can see literally nothing happened to that last question apart from it being posted and deleted). Adding preemptive warnings to this system is... on my list. –  Shog9" ([source](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6599/why-do-i-get-questionblock-after-just-two-deleted-questions/6600#comment17792_6600)) so some warning system *is* on SE's radar, though designing it such that it doesn't lead to gaming sitting on the edge of a ban is likely the challenging part.