# How to make a meta question more likely to be answered?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties, meta

**Question**

1. How can I make this question, [Improving Question-Asking - Looking for Suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170540/210573) more attractive to the SO community?
2. Why has it not been answered, despite the reputation and up votes?

**Note:** Please make your answer not just applicable to me, but to the rest of the community. I am sure that this has happened to others. Most likely, I will give at least +50 to a good answer.

**Background**

I recently asked a question, [Improving Question-Asking - Looking for Suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170540/210573), and I have been unable to garner any answers - I don't care about rep on Meta - *I just care that a solution is given.*

Once it became apparent that no matter how many upvotes I received the question would still go un-answered, I decided to add a massive (for me) +150 bounty: this question *had* to be solved.

Now, three days into the bounty process, only several other people have looked at it, and no new comments or answers have been given. Why?

Comment: Your question is broad and comprises of many different questions which aren't particularly related to each other and have already been discussed on Meta. Questions need focus. That one is just hit-and-miss on many key points, some of which require more in-depth investigation into your account. Ultimately what I see is a big "please audit all my behavior for the site" which no one here is really willing to do, and thus you haven't gotten any answers.

Comment: What is the reason for all the down votes?

Comment: There are many questions that go unanswered for one reason or another. That doesn't mean every unanswered question should spawn more questions about how to get an answer, like some sort of hydra. Most of the questions you are asking there can be answered from a perusal of existing questions here on Meta, which is why I suspect no one added any new answers. Try looking carefully through [The FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: Just relax. You write as though you are affronted by people not answering your questions. It happens. If you want to learn look at other questions and other styles. Most questions and answers that get upvotes do so because it's apparent a person has put some effort in. I'm not saying you haven't. It's just you come across as a bit too intense.

Comment: You should totally drop all this and try jQuery.

Answer (score 8):

A few thoughts.

Any question that contains a two-paragraph *introduction*, three paragraphs in, is probably too long. Folks will take a look, see a half-hour and two pages of their lives disappear, and walk away. Much of what you've got there isn't necessary. Trim it down, and you'll get less of the Great Wall Of Text problem.

You're asking for an in-depth review of your questions and others' answers:

> 1. What could I have done to avoid the downvotes?
> 2. How can I make my questions relevant to others?
> 3. How can I increase the clarity of my questions?

That's the middle third of your post, asking about improving one of your existing questions. One could go on for *pages* on just one of those points. I'm exhausted just thinking about how to approach that (well, that, and I've been refactoring a large project all day, with another few weeks of work to go).

It's great that you want feedback - you're trying to improve. But you're asking for too much at once.

The bounty is nice, but Meta... rep matters even less here than it does on SO.

Comment: To answer your earlier question, *how could I improve?*: read Jon Skeet's epic set of suggestions, [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).